# Как общаться с PreferenceHelper минуя DataManager в MVP?

Tags: android, mvp

Использую шаблон проектирования `MVP`. Для наглядности приложу картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень часто нужно просто записать данные в `PreferenceHelper` из презентера, но нужно это делать через `DataManager`. Приходиться дублировать методы из `PreferenceHelper` в `DataManager`. Можно ли этого избежать? (Наследование явно не предлагать) Общаться на прямую с `PreferenceHelper` думаю не правильно.

**PS**
Делать например метод:

```
fun getData(dataKey: String, datatype: T) : T {}
```

считаю не вариант, так можно перепутать с типом, и получить краш в одном из сценариев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, но не нужно. 
"*Расставляя капканы*"

`SharedPreferences`, это источник данных как и БД. У вас на схеме всё верно. Если вы `PreferencesHelper` положите в **Presenter**(или **View**), data слой (**MODEL**) не узнает, вы срежете угол, а там капкан. 
*"Почему это плохо? ведь я его вижу и не попался?"* 
Если завтра вы из префов забираете данные, но захотели и кешировать или писать БД, или необходимо с какими-то данными выйти в сеть - мы нарушаем
singleResponsibility и архитектура начнет понемногу шататься. Вам придется еще больше дублировать методы и думать почему в 2 (или более) местах имеем доступ к тому же самому классу, а так DataManager (Repository) разобрался бы какие данные отдавать, кешировать, преобразовать для presentation layer.

В целом это довольно частый вопрос в Android архитектуре и permissions, bundle, uri, states, services и тд. Много проектов, где шли коротким путем как хотите вы, в живых осталоись немногие, ведь вы уже пошли дальше, а вот коллеги про тот *капкан узнают уже поздно.*)